# Физика машины в unity2d

Tags: unity3d

Создал машинку в Unity2d, повесил на колеса HingeJoint2d, после выключения двигателя машина продолжает бесконечно двигаться туда назад на неровностях.
В чем может быть проблема?

Код скрипта движения машинки который висит на обоих колесах

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class CarPhysics : MonoBehaviour {
    HingeJoint2D[] wheelJoins;                      
    JointMotor2D backWheel;                

    public ClickScript[] ControlCar;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {               
        if (ControlCar[0].clickedIs == true)
        {             
           backWheel = GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>().motor ;
            backWheel.motorSpeed = backWheel.motorSpeed = 10000;
            GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>().motor = backWheel;
            GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>().useMotor = true;    
        }
        else if(ControlCar[0].clickedIs == false)
        {
            backWheel = GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>().motor;
            backWheel.motorSpeed = backWheel.motorSpeed =0;
            GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>().motor = backWheel;
            GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>().useMotor = false;
        }

    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю что проблема в недостаче трения, которое при выключенном двигателе (и при не нажатом тормозе) постепенно тормозило машинку. Как в RigidBody добавить трение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Свойства первого колеса (1). Как повесить трение на колеса?

Comment: Код, скриншоты?

Comment: Вы делаете неправильный вопрос. Не давайте ответы к СВОЕМУ вопросу, как дополнение. Лучше редактируйте свой вопрос, кнопкой "править" и добавьте то что вы написали ниже. А потом те ответы, которые вы дали ниже - удалите.

Comment: я немогу добавлять больше 1го скрина в вопрос(репутация не позволяет), если есть еще какой-то метод добавления скажите пожалуйста

Comment: @Dualist можно попробовать добавить ссылки в вопрос и как-то пометить это, чтоб из очереди проверок пришёл дядя и поправил)